# Cut one big horizontal artwork to multiple different artwork in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, slices, behance

I am new on Behance and the design community. I designed my final image to upload on Behance in one artwork horizontally stretching, now I want to save this artwork file to multiple images and I don't know how to cut it to multiple other artwork to save/export each artwork into different images.

Comment: Please show a specific example and also be specific on how you want to cut: into two similar halves? Or unevenly into one fifth, two fifths and another two fifths? This will help other users to give you specific examples in their answers, which makes answering much easier and will get you more and better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Slice Tool** to divide your artwork

[image]

When ready, **Save for Web**: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> Windows. Choose the file format export options and select **Export: All Slices**

[image]

Comment: This is by far best solution to this problem and thanks for that but i was thinking if there might be another better way as in this you have to slice very carefully or edit that slice to artwork after. I have rectangle background for each different image i want to export, can we use that rectangle path as to create different slices or different exports?

Comment: Of course there is a way, but you should have included this subject in your question originally, if as you get answers you change the content of your question, this becomes a custom tutorial and nobody is here to work for free.

Comment: it's my first time posting so, I don't know a lot about how it works anyhow I figured that out we can Object>slice>Create from Guides, Object>slice>make for selected rectangle paths. Thanks for pointing to it!